# Javascript Extract Specific ID value from Array to another Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, local-storage

I have result array on script like this:

```
var myurlsave = [{"url_field":"yahoo","enabled":true},{"url_field":"google","enabled":true},{"url_field":"bing","enabled":true}];
```

I want to extract it to look like this:

```
var myurlname = ["yahoo", "google", "bing"];
```

I think it looks easy for you but I having hard time for this. Thank you for your help

Comment: Java is not Javascript. Mind your tags!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var arr = myurlsave.map(function(a) {
    return a.url_field;
});
```

Comment: for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control

Comment: best shortcut answer. Thank you. But I have problem on chrome extension. NO result if I am using var myurlsave = localStorage.result; from options.js

Comment: @Will Reese actually the value 
`[{"url_field":"yahoo","enabled":true},{"url_field":"google","enabled":true},{"url_field":"bing","enabled":true}]`
is a result from localStorage.result if I will use `var myurlsave = localStorage.result` there will no output on `var arr`

Answer (score 1):

Learn functional programming and look into the `map` function.

What you basically want to do is apply a transformation to each element in your array. The transformation here does not mean to 'change' the element in the array, but do some function on it and get a new value as a result.

In this case, the function that performs the needed transformation is:

```
function extract_url(object) {
    return object.url_field
}
```

Now, you want to apply this to every element and get a new array:

```
var newArray = originalArray.map(extract_url)
```

A simpler way to achieve this if you don't understand functional programming is a simple loop:

```
var newArray = []
for(var i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
     var item = originalArray[i];
     var newItem = extract_url(item)
     newArray.push(newItem)
}
```