# Javascript extract or map specific id/value from another script result

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, local-storage

Followup question from here: [Old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44015147/javascript-extract-specific-id-value-from-array-to-another-array/44015169#44015169)

This result come from other file script called `localStorage.result`
output is: `[{"url_field":"yahoo","enabled":true},{"url_field":"google","enabled":true},{"url_field":"bing","enabled":true}]`

To extract specific ID/value I use this code:

```
var myurlsave = localStorage.result;
var arr = myurlsave.map(function(a) {
    return a.url_field;
});
```

This code above has no result or output. But when I write manually the result of  `localStorage.result` like this:

```
var myurlsave = [{"url_field":"yahoo","enabled":true},{"url_field":"google","enabled":true},{"url_field":"bing","enabled":true}];
    var arr = myurlsave.map(function(a) {
        return a.url_field;
    });
```

There will be a result that I need: `var arr = ["yahoo", "google", "bing"]`
But I need to use the `var myurlsave = localStorage.result` because this dynamical change base on users input.

Thank you for the help

Comment: Is `localStorage.result` a string? In which case you need to deserialise it: `JSON.parse(localStorage.result)`; Also, check the console for errors.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan - OMG! i forgot the JSON.parse. That's what I need. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of your logic it would appear that `localStorage.result` is a string. In this case you need to deserialise it to an object:

```
var myurlsave = JSON.parse(localStorage.result);
var arr = myurlsave.map(function(a) {
    return a.url_field;
});
```